# class related issue in PHP

Tags: php, class

I have a doubt in class concept that when we extend a class in php and define an same attribute in that class(derived) which was defined in base class then is it ok or not and why?

Comment: It depends how you want it to work.

Comment: I have problems to parse the meaning of your sentence, could you please extend the question or spray some punctuation in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the access modifiers and what you want to achieve.

First of all, if you declare your var `private`, then, the var is only known inside the class, it is declared.

If you want it to be available in any child class, but not from the outside, it should be `protected`.

Any other var (public available from everywhere) have to be `public`. But using public isn't recommned, because of data encapsulation. Instead of using public vars, you should write getters/setters.

At least, it's not a good idea, to mix vars with the same name, but different access modifiers - this leads to unreadable/confusing code.

Comment: so it will show no error or notice if I use same public variable name in derived class as same in base class?